# How to upload text file (specific format) to java script array in flask app?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I have a text file in my static folder that contains a list of specific colleges that I want to use for my autocomplete search in my html page.

This is the format of the text file (college_list.txt):

```
["college1", "college2", ... "final college"]
```

This is my autocomplete function in my layout template:

```
<!-- Autocomplete JS -->
    <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
         $(function() {
            var collegeList  =  [
               UPLOADED LIST HERE!!!!
            ];
            $( "#college_search" ).autocomplete({
               source: collegeList
            });
         });
     </script>
```

```
- routes.py
- models.py
- forms.py
- static
    - college_list.txt
-templates
    - layout.html (where I want to upload the college_list into autocomplete function)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your `college_list.txt` be formatted like this:

```
College 1
College 2
College 3
.
.
final college
```

In `routes.py` add a new route `/colleges` to get the list of colleges as json

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify 
...
import os

@app.route('/colleges')
def get_college_list():
    with open(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'college_list.txt'), "r") as f:
        colleges = [college.rstrip() for college in f.readlines()]
    return jsonify({"colleges" : colleges})
```

In your `layout.html` modify your script to get college list using ajax call

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#college_search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./colleges",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.colleges);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>>
```

Comment: after adding your suggestion, I now get the error "simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" when trying to run the flask app from terminal @waynetech

Comment: Did you re-format your `college_list.txt` as shown? Each college name in a new line without quotes (") and brackets [ ] we use in array

Comment: yes I have, I even created a smaller text file list to test it out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `print(colleges)`  just before `return jsonify({"colleges" : colleges})` in your routes and check your logs, what result you are getting? post the print output, it will be just above where the error occurs (before traceback). you can also change your `return` to `return jsonify({"colleges" : 0})` to avoid error and check print output

Comment: I see the problem, I was also using the text file in forms.py, and I just neede to update that as well with the new format. Thanks!